# is not a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am trying to create two classes : lista and iterator . Iterator will be a friend of the class lista. The problem is that when I declare the class iterator I get this error : iterator is not a template class .
These are the two file.h

**lista .h :**

```
*#include "nodo.h"*

template <class T>

class lista{

public :

    //all the function

private :
    nodo<T> *list;
    nodo<T> *tail;
    int n;


    friend class iterator<T>;


};
```

**iterator.h :**

```
*#include "lista.h"*

template<class Z>

class iterator {

public :

    lista<Z> a;
    iterator();
};
```

Comment: `friend class iterator<T>;` should probably be `template<class U> friend class iterator;`.

Comment: @BoPersson How so? `T` is the class' template parameter. The problem is that `iterator` isn't defined at this point (at `friend class iterator<T>`). Use forward-declaration.

Comment: @Nelxiost Template parameters aren't _inherited_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't see inheritance here. I might be terribly mistaken, but [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a2a9210a739ae75) compiles.

Comment: @Nelxiost You're correct for most-restrictive friending. Unless you want to friend **all** instantiations of `iterator` to *all* instantiations of `lista`, a forward decl is warranted. Friending with `template<class U> friend class iterator;` allows `iterator<int>` to be friended to `lista<double>`. If that isn't desirable (it usually isn't) forward-decl + friending as you show is preferred (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward declare `iterator<T>` so `lista<T>` knows that it exists.

```
// Forward declaration of iterator<T>
template <class T>
class iterator;

template <class T>
class lista {
    ...
    friend class iterator<T>;
};
```

Although not necessary, I recommend implementing an iterator for `lista` as an inner class of `lista`.  It is then obvious to the casual reader that the iterator is meant as an iterator for the containing class.